# Node.js mongoose update documents

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm confused about best practices to update certain documents in node, for example, I don't know if I should update multiple fields through req.body (which would make everything easier for me):

```
//course is the document and Course is the model
util.updateDocument(course, Course, req.body);
```

or if I should create several post methods each with one field of the document to update and request them in a row from the client:

```
app.put('/updatecourse/:field1',function(req, res){});
app.put('/updatecourse/:field2',function(req, res){});
app.put('/updatecourse/:field3',function(req, res){});
```

Currently I'm using the function that receives any field of the document through req.body and updates it, but from what I heard that is not a good practice, plus the methods are not asynchronous. Can someone explain to me what are the best practices for this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always prefer to have a REST API for each of my models. So the solution I can give you is the example of the `UPDATE` operation:

```js
app.put('courses/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  var id = req.params.id,
       body = req.body;
  
  Courses.findById(id, function(error, course) {
    // Handle the error using the Express error middleware
    if(error) return next(error);
    
    // Render not found error
    if(!course) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: 'Course with id ' + id + ' can not be found.'
      });
    }
    
    // Update the course model
    course.update(body, function(error, course) {
      if(error) return next(error);
      
      res.json(course);
    });
  });
});
```

Here you will expect that the route is triggered with an `id`(or Mongoose `_id`) parameter. First we would like to check if the Model exists for that ID, if it does not, we would return a NotFound response with a `404` Status Code. If the model exists update it with new properties.

In Mongoose, you can update the model using the `findByIdAndUpdate` method as well. This is an atomic operation on the database, and no Model validation or default values are applied. Also the pre/post hooks would not be triggered.

[Check here for the documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)

```js
app.put('courses/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  var id = req.params.id,
       body = req.body;
  
  Courses.findByIdAndUpdate(id, body, function(error, courses) {
    // Handle the error using the Express error middleware
    if(error) return next(error);
    
    // Render not found error
    if(!course) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: 'Course with id ' + id + ' can not be found.'
      });
    }

    res.json(course);
  });
});
```

Comment: If I want to update only one field of the doc, update overwrites that field only or it overwrites the whole document? (in that case erasing the other fields)

Comment: It will change the only the fields that are set inside the `body`. So if the Model has `prop1` and `prop2` and the body has only a value for `prop2`, the `prop1` will be left unchanged while the `prop2` will be updated.

Comment: Oh that's what I've been looking for, thanks! I will test it out here.